# Use an open connection for all Linq DataContexts

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I'm developing a large scale website and when I was checking linq queries with SQL Profiler I found that there is about 30 login/logout actions. I want to decrease these actions by using an open connection for all DataContexts but I don't know how to do it. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is pretty bad idea - you are creating large scalable website so let Linq-to-sql handle connection itself.

Linq-to-sql internally handles connection opening and releasing in effective way for it usage. It uses default ADO.NET connection pooling so the connection is correctly reused and not opened for every single context.

Using single connection for all context is exactly what makes your application non scalable and not working. Single connection allows only single transaction so once two requests want to make concurrent changes and use their own transaction your application will crash.

Do not share contexts and do not share connections - let ADO.NET handle connection pooling and create new context for every single request or you can expect serious issues.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka - From your answer it sounds that creating a DataContext instance doesn't mean a new connection to database is created. Can you please confirm that? Everywhere I read seems to indicate otherwise. Can you please provide a link to how database connections are created and released in case of linq-to-sql?

Comment: @Brian: It is not about linq-to-sql but about connection pooling used by default when you connect to SQL server. You can think about that like reusing network connection (instead of opening it every single time your DataContext needs to fetch or persist data).

Comment: @LadislavMrnka - Does that mean nothing additional happens on '.NET' side? I want to make sure I understand it correctly - if I have two 'using' statements that create new datacontexts, one after the other, on the .NET side of things, is there any connection pooling involved? Or as far as clr is concerned, they are both two brand new connections?

Comment: @Brian: Unless you turn it off in connection string, the connection pool is involved but that is a right way to use it. Each context still have its own "logical" connection even if the second reuses the physical connection created for the first context and after that stored in the pool.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka - Got it. Thank you. Can you please any links that discuss this in depth?